# For a list of list (we call it A), I want to have a different list of list. see details below?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose I have a list of list.

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,4,6,8,9,10], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Now I want to a list of list such as

```
[[1,2,0,0,0,0], [2,4,0,0,0,0], [10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Is there a quick way to do it instead of using a loop to modify it. Thank you.

Edit: sorry for the confusion. I like to keep first *x* elements and modify rest to `0`. 
The size of each sublist is same.

Comment: What precisely are you looking for? Do you want to replace specific elements with `0`s? Please edit your question to fully the standard in [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please add your logic to your question. Do you need to zero-out the last 4 elements of each sublist?

Comment: I want to keep the first x elements, and change the rest to 0. Thanks.

Comment: Is the size of each sublist the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
for lst in my_list:
    lst[2:]=[0,0,0,0]
print(my_list)
#[[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

If you have different sizes of lists in list and you want to change only last 4 items to *0* try this.

```
for lst in my_list:
    lst[-4:]=[0,0,0,0]
```

---

**EDIT:**

*I want to keep the first x elements, and change the rest to 0.*

Try this.

```
lst[x-len(lst):]=[0 for i in range(len(lst)-x)] #suggested by dcg
```

Or

```
lst[x:]=[0]*(len(lst)-x)
```

Comment: `lst[x-len(lst):]=[0 for i in range(len(lst)-x)]`

Comment: Or `lst[x:]=[0]*(len(lst)-x)` @dcg

Comment: @dcg Added them to the answer

Answer (score 0):

The following code is what you need:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # list modification with zeros
    alist = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,4,6,8,9,10], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]

    for x in alist: 
        x[2:] = [0]*4

    print(alist)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: What's the reason behind using `i` why not use enumerate? And `x[2:]=...` modified list in place you dont need to again do `alist[i]=x`.

Comment: I use ```i``` to parse and modify the ```alist``` appropriately.

Comment: There's no need to use `i`. `x[2:]=[0]*4` is enough. No need to do `alist[i]=x`.

Comment: I see, what you mean. Thanks, I modified appropriately.